# How Can I See The Query That NHibernate Generates?

Tags: nhibernate

Currently I have some event listeners setup to log all insert/update/delete actions that happen. I just go through the list of properties and build a string to insert into an audit table.

What I'd really like to do is get the raw SQL query that NHibernate generates. Just like what NHProf shows.

How would I do this?

Comment: You may use SQL Server Profiler too.

Comment: I need to to save the query off for auditing purposes; hence using the event listeners before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `<property name="show_sql">true</property>` in your config file to make it output the SQL to the console.

You can also put `<property name="format_sql">true</property>` if you want it PrettyPrinted.

Alternatively, you can configure log4net (logger is "NHibernate.SQL", IIRC) and send it anywhere you want.

Comment: How do I get it in code if it's being output to the console? I need it in code so I can insert it into the database as an audit log.

Comment: Did you read the last part? (BTW, I think that's what nhprof does)

Comment: Hmm... From Ayende's post here http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/10/21/nhprof-logging-interception.aspx and looking at the files included with NHProf, i.e. HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.dll, it seems to be a custom log4net appender is being used. I'll look into that. Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I was able to create a custom log4net appender, hook into it via code, and I can see all the SQL statements just like they show up in NHProf. This will work, but is there a way to get the same results using event listeners instead? That would be ideal.

Comment: No, SQL is not exposed to event listeners (it's a lower level)